# Are there any pitfalls to using Any vs specific argument type?

Tags: scala, types, arguments

Suppose I want a method to output *something*, a string or integer in this case. I can do it like this:

```
def outString(str: String) {
    str // or "return str"
}
```

and run it like this: `outString("foo")`

But I can also avoid initializing a specific type as an argument and it'll work:

```
def outString(str: Any) {
    str
}
```

and run it either like this: `outString("foo")` or `outString(123)`.

Given that they both work and assuming a situation where you don't always know the type of the argument passed, is there any pitfalls in using `Any` over specific argument types? Does `Any` do any type of automatic type checking like interpreted languages do that would slow the code down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no practical difference between the following two methods in terms of runtime performance, etc.:

```
def genericLog[A](a: A): Unit = println(a.toString)
def anyLog(a: Any): Unit = println(a.toString)
```

As long as you're only using the methods on `Any` and not performing runtime type checks or casts with `isInstanceOf` or `asInstanceOf` or pattern matching, there's no performance impact.

The problem is that [there aren't many things you can do with `Any`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Any), and the things you can do (check equality and convert to a string) aren't very useful (try printing an array, for example). As soon as you need to write something like this:

```
def anyLog(a: Any): Unit = a match {
  case i: Int => println("Int: " + i)
  case s: String => println("String: " + s)
  case other => println("Other: " + other)
}
```

You're back in the land of runtime type checking, which does have a performance impact, but more importantly undermines the ability of you and others to reason about your code.

So yeah, if you're absolutely certain that you'll never need to do anything except call `toString`, you can use `Any` here. This kind of case isn't likely to come up very often if you're writing idiomatic Scala code, though, and I'd personally suggest categorically avoiding `Any` *everywhere*, including in cases like this.

---

Update: As @pedrofurla points out in a comment below, there is one important difference between a method that takes an `Int` argument and one that takes `Any`. In the `Any`-taking method, an integer argument will be boxed, while it won't (necessarily) in the `Int`-taking method.

It's very, very easy to end up accidentally boxing primitives in Scala (`1.toString` or `println(1)` will do it, for example), and in general it's probably not something you should worry about until benchmarking or a profiler have told you it's a problem in a particular case. But this is yet another reason to avoid `Any` arguments, since both a non-generic `Int` argument or a generic argument with a `@specialized` annotation won't result in unnecessary boxing.

Comment: Ah.. beat me by 2 seconds.

Comment: @m-z If you think your answer's better you should post it! :)

Comment: Ha, I don't think so. It would look much the same, minus a couple details.

Comment: This makes it much clearer. Although I can still print an `Array` with `Any` as initialized param. It means I have to know from the beginning what the method will handle unlike interpreted languages do. I was *almost* thinking about making Scala behave like an interpreted language.

Comment: @AlperTuran, take another look at Travis's first example. The way not to have to know the type from the beginning is to make it a generic function. So, in your case `def outstr[A](x:A) = { x }`

Comment: What about boxing of JVM primitive types? Won't `Any` arguments box them? For example anyLog(1) will become something like `anyLog(new java.lang.Integer(1))`.

Comment: @pedrofurla Yeah, good point—both the generic and `Any` versions will box the integer (although it's so easy to end up accidentally boxing stuff in Scala that I tend to think trying to avoid it is something that should only happen after you've profiled your application). I'll update the answer when I'm back at a computer.

Comment: @TravisBrown, completely agree, I take the same approach myself, only mentioned as a "good to remember" thing.